# how to scroll to an anchor point with smooth animation adobe edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

I can't find this seemingly simple answer. I am trying to make an animated button on my site scroll to an anchor point on my site(it's just one huge page)

The code I currently have in the code snippet box in edge doesn't work. It's kind of frustrating because with edge you're not entirely sure where your code is being thrown into the end result.

```
// insert code for mouse click here
window.scrollTo(0,0);


//want it to scroll to #Main
```

most of the code in edge starts you off with:

```
sys.someAction()
```

Here's my site if you want to look at what I'm trying to do:
www.daniellachman.com

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the full code snippet, provided with the code supplied below:

```
  //Edge binding end
  //CUSTOM CODE FROM Monty82
  function scrollToTag(tagName) {
  var myTag = $("a[name='"+ tagName +"']");
  $('html,body').stop(false,false).animate({scrollTop: myTag.offset().top}, 'slow');
}

    //Edge binding end
    //Original Mouse Clicking Function Provided by Edge
  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_newlogoheader}", "click", function(sym, e) {
  // insert code for mouse click here
  //Stuff I added to call custom function above
  sym.scrollToTag("main")


  });
```

It didn't work. But I feel like I'm on the right track.
www.daniellachman.com

If anyone knows how to look at the javascript for the menu nav buttons "about" "contact" and see what that is referencing for the scroll. I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

This function in JavaScript/jQuery may help you:

```
function scrollToTag(tagName) {
    var myTag = $("a[name='"+ tagName +"']");
    $('html,body').stop(false,false).animate({scrollTop: myTag.offset().top}, 'slow');
}
```

The parameter is the name (not the id but the name) of the anchor to which you want to scroll.

Notice that the function is designed for vertical scrolling, your site seems to require vertical and horizontal, so you may need to use `scrollLeft` too.

Comment: Thanks, so just to inquire further: if my html I want to scroll to is "http://daniellachman.com/#main" where/what would I plug in?

Comment: In that case, when you click the button that triggers the scrolling action, you would call the function like `scrollToTag("main")`.

Comment: I've provided the full code snippet in an edit, painfully trying to incorporate your code, but I wasn't sure how to modify it.

Comment: is `symbolName` the name in the tag?

Comment: I'm not sure what the symbolName is. It's hard to understand the references in edge.

Comment: I'd say: move the function I sent you outside the function you have placed it in. Then, right after the `//insert code for mouse click here` just put a call to the function for the main anchor (if you only want the main one): `scrollToTag("main")`

Comment: last time, Thanks I think i did the coding right, now it's just not actually working. I have the snippet above with all the relevant code. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without the `sym.` part? Using `scrollToTag("main")` instead of `sym.scrollToTag("main")`

Comment: yeah I did both, it didn't work either way. I also did both with or without the ; at the end of the function call "scrollToTag("main");" I wish there was a way I could see what the other buttons are doing like "about" and "contact" I can't seem to locate the actual function in the Chrome Inspector

Comment: I don't know how edge works, so I won't be able to help with that. Good luck and don't forget to post the solution once you find it